# Swift 3.0 TableViewCell: Saving the Status of a Button and Having it Persist

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button

Currently, I have a tableview set up subclassing a tableviewcell. On this tableviewcell I have a button that displays add or display. I was wondering if there was a way to store the status of the button with respect to its row. For example, I have a search bar along with this tableview and if I changed the status of the button of the 4th row of my tableview to subtract, from add, and then search the specific row in my search bar, it will show up on the first row, but will not retain the status of the button. I was wondering if there was a way to do this without the use of backend (or database).

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = data.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text as NSString
        let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if (filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false
    } else {
        searchActive = true
    }
    self.TableView.reloadData()
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Hello")

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchActive == true {
        return filtered.count
    }
    return data.count
}

var status = [IndexPath: Bool]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ListCell
    cell.cellDelegate = self
    cell.contentView.bringSubview(toFront: cell.Button)


    if status[indexPath] ?? false {

        cell.Button.setTitle("Subtract", for: .normal)
    } else {

        cell.Button.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
    }

    cell.indexPath = indexPath

    if(searchActive) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.contentView.bringSubview(toFront: cell.Button)
    return cell
}

func didPressButton(indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let cell = TableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ListCell else {
        return
    }

    if status[indexPath] ?? false {
        status[indexPath] = false
        cell.Button.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)

    } else {
        status[indexPath] = true
        cell.Button.setTitle("Subtract", for: .normal)

    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have code to track the status; what is happening or not working?

Comment: Well yes, if I click the button, it will change the status say from Add -> Subtract, and I can revert this back to Add by clicking it again. What I am interested in is when I set any row to Subtract, and then search it using my search bar, the button status will not persist, as it takes the button status of the first row (or first few, however much it filters). I was wondering how I can get the button status to filter along with the data.

Comment: You haven't shown any code to do with searching, so it is impossible to say what the problem is.

Comment: I've edited my question to add info relevant to the searchBar.

Comment: Your problem is that your `status` array is indexed by the same indices as the `data` array, so when you are using the `filtered` array the `status` values don't map.  You could use a dictionary of `[String:Bool]` for your `status` values, where the key would be the relevant value from the `data` array.  Then `status` would be independent of the index

Comment: I had similar problem some time ago and it worked when I used `currentTitle`. Could you try that?

Comment: As mentioned by others, the indexPath will change between different searches and therefore cannot be used. Does the data you're displaying have some form of unique key? If so, `status` should be a dictionary of that key, which you can then lookup in `cellForRowAt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for guiding me with this. Here's what I have that works. In my data array I've added another entry within each item that is unique (A,B,C). I then use 
 this key value in my status array to determine whether or not it has been added or not. Please let me know if there is a more efficient way to do so.

```
var data = [["Apples","A"],["Bananas","B"],["Corn","C"],["Doughnuts","D"],["Eggplant","E"],["Flour","F"]]
var filtered: [[String]] = []
var searchActive : Bool = false 
var status = [String: Bool]()
var name : String = String()
var filteredName : String = String()

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = data.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text[0] as NSString
        let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if (filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false
    } else {
        searchActive = true
    }
    self.guestTableView.reloadData()
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Hello")  
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchActive == true {
        return filtered.count
    }
    return data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! GuestListCell
    cell.cellDelegate = self
    cell.contentView.bringSubview(toFront: cell.button)


    item = data[indexPath.row][1]


    if status[item] ?? false {
        cell.button.setTitle("Subtract", for: .normal)
    } else {
        cell.button.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
    }

    cell.indexPath = indexPath

    if(searchActive) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row][0]

        if status[filtered[indexPath.row][1]] ?? false {
            cell.button.setTitle("Subtract", for: .normal)
        } else {
            cell.button.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
        }
    } else {
        filteredName = data[indexPath.row][1]
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row][0]
    }
    cell.contentView.bringSubview(toFront: cell.button)
    return cell
}

func didPressButton(indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let cell = guestTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? GuestListCell else {
        return
    }

    if searchActive {

        if status[filtered[indexPath.row][1]] ?? false {
            print("the value of searchActive is \(searchActive)")
            status[filtered[indexPath.row][1]] = false
            cell.button.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
        } else {
            status[filtered[indexPath.row][1]] = true
            cell.button.setTitle("Subtract", for: .normal)

        }

    } else {

        if status[data[indexPath.row][1]] ?? false {

            status[data[indexPath.row][1]] = false
            cell.button.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
        } else {
            status[data[indexPath.row][1]] = true
            cell.button.setTitle("Subtract", for: .normal)
        }
    }

}
```